# Run loop an extra time if one of the inputs is bad

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for-loop which asks for scores between 0 and 10. It asks a certain amount depending on the number of judges.

Here's the code:

```
        System.out.println("Number of judges: ");
        int numOfJudges = IO.readInt();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<numOfJudges; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter judge's score: ");
            int score = IO.readInt();

            if (score >= 0 && score <= 10) {
            sum += score;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect number, must be between 0 and 10.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

I want to make is so if a number is entered that's not between 0 and 10, it won't count that as one of the conditions as `i < numOfJudges`. 
For example if I have 3 judges and I enter 2 wrong inputs, it will still only run the loop 3 times (and only take the good input into account) while I really want it to run 5 times to make up for the two incorrect inputs.

Comment: What if you added `i--;` in the `else` statement also on line 7 you did `System.out.print("Enter judge's score: ");` but you missed the `ln` after `print`

Answer (score 1):

Increment `numOfJudges` in case of ELSE condition so that your FOR loop would run until you have desired number of correct inputs.

This is shortest and cleanest solution.

```
else {
    System.out.println("Incorrect number, must be between 0 and 10.");
    numOfJudges++;
}
```

Comment: Did you get a chance give a try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop inside of the for-loop, instead of adjusting the for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<numOfJudges; i++) {
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Enter judge's score: ");
        int score = IO.readInt();

        if (score >= 0 && score <= 10) {
            sum += score;
            break; //jump out of while-loop
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect number, must be between 0 and 10.");
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```